# Facebook Object Debugger: property 'og:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'

Tags: facebook-opengraph

When I run my Facebook Open Graph object (http://www.21dads.com/testobject) through the Object Debugger, I'm getting the following errors:

> Object Invalid Value: Object at URL 'http://www.21dads.com/testobject'
>   of type 'thetestasdf:recipie' is invalid because the given value
>   'www.21dads.com/testobject' for property 'og:url' could not be parsed
>   as type 'url'.
>
> Missing Required Property:    The og:url property is required, but not
>   present.
>
> Missing Required Property:    The og:type property is required, but not
>   present.
>
> Missing Required Property:    The og:title property is required, but not
>   present.

Here is the HTML on the object page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# thetestasdf: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/thetestasdf#">
      <meta property="fb:app_id"      content="325291980834949" />
      <meta property="og:type"        content="thetestasdf:recipie" />
      <meta property="og:url"         content="www.21dads.com/testobject" />
      <meta property="og:title"       content="Cookie Recipie!" />
      <meta property="og:description" content="Tastiest recipe ever" />
      <meta property="og:image"       content="http://cdn.techpatio.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/cookie_law_eu.gif" />
      <title> Cookie Recipie</title>
    <head/>

    <body>
        <p> Test object page </p>
    </body>

</html>
```

The URL "www.21dads.com/testobject" is my controller which then generates the HTML from a view file. Why can't this URL be parsed?

Why am I getting the other "missing required property" errors when they are already included?

Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should have scheme in front of `og:url` content (like `http://` or `https://` ), or this isn't URL.

In your specific case you should replace `www.21dads.com/testobject` with `http://www.21dads.com/testobject`

Comment: i'm sharing a local url.. `file:///Users/station7/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D6AEE0A4-B0F9-4EB5-BA48-514B0281984F/data/Containers/Data/Application/6809A643-9F2A-45A3-9C9C-AEDEE47D71D0/tmp/uTVoP5IdSFg59FC.mp4` and i have the same error

Comment: @jose920405 the URL should be reachable by the linter

Comment: I had this error because my url had a leading whitespace: " http://..."

Comment: In my case I had to remove www from the url

Comment: trailing slash vs. no trailing slash triggered the error for me.

Comment: Checking from a different test/dev page with a canonical to the production page can also cause all kinds of bizarre behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

Roundup / checklist of possible issues to check for:

- Make sure your meta tag matches http:// or https:// in the URL.
- Make sure your meta tag matches www or non-www in the URL.
- *(Sidenote: You should pick one combo of http/https www/non-www and redirect all of your traffic to that URL anyways, and make sure that matches your og:url meta tag)*
- Check for whitespace before or after the URL
- Check for a trailing slash forced by Facebook that may not be in your meta tag
- Check for duplicated "og:url" meta tags
- Check that your URL is publicly available (you can't use the online debugger successfully for a localhost install - check it once you're on a staging or production site that's publicly available). Double check that you're not on a password-protected or IP address restricted environment.
- Check your spelling - is the URL really correct?
- Scrape the URL again. If you fixed it, you need to re-scrape, not just try again.

Comment: Whitespace got me. Thanks for having that in your list :)

Comment: Great list!  Please add something to the effect that:  "Make sure you are checking from the canonical production page instead of from a test/dev page with a URL different from the canonical"

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use this https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ for see what is exactly scrapped. Anyway facebook say they are using open graph, but a lot of personnals test seems to say they don't.

Comment: I used this tool. The cached version had an error.  When I clicked fetch new, the error was gone.  Looks like an intermittent FB issue.  Real sharing worked after this too.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible reason for this could be duplicated Open Graph Meta tags.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful while using hyperlink through the comment plugin.
< div class=" fb - comm en ts" data - href ="http://website.com/view.php?id=323" data-width="100%" data-numposts="20">

I was using https:// instead of http:// (because I didn't have the SSL installed on the server.)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. The description below my posts when shared to FB, showed a lot of strange words such as  but only for some of my posts (some were correct). I did below steps and fixed my problem (I don't know any coding):

1- In my wp-admin, I checked the 'TEXT' rather than 'VISUAL' where I could strangely see my description as well as all those rubbish words such as  so I got rid of any extra word and saved.

2- In https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/, I typed the post page URL and pushed "Fetch New Scrape Information"

And ta..rrraaa! It was fixed!