# Facebook page "Like" in iPhone App

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

How the Facebook Page `Like` can be implemented in iPhone App?

Comment: Check this discussion on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112847/facebook-ios-sdk-3-0-implement-like-action-on-a-url

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Facebook offers tools, services and SDKs to developers who want to integrate social experiences into their apps. Whether your app is on [iOS, Android, mobile web or desktop web](https://developers.facebook.com/docs).

In iOS SDK there are many options like.

- Share Login
- Ads App Events
- Graph API
- Open Graph Dialogs and UI
- Controls App Center

Here is a list of all the samples apps for the [Facebook SDK for iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/sample-apps/).

Comment: Can u pls help me to implement the Like functionality?

Comment: I think this information will help you a lot. please try it first as search, learn as put your reasonable query on SO. or update your question.

Comment: I believe OP was trying to use the API to 'like' a Facebook Page on behalf of their app's users, that is not possible

Comment: `Is it possible to do Like a Facebook page from my iPhone App?` and yes it is using `Facebook iOS SDK`. that's what i wrote in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

you can use FaceBook sdk provided by www.facebook.com to implement in native coding or you can use iframe to load like widgets in UIWebView.